# Advantage of using `ndk-build` instead of `make`

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there any advantage of using the NDK build system `ndk-build` and `Android.mk` to build ndk project instead of using standalone toolchain and `Makefile` / `make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndk-build` is just a wrapper around `make`. You can see that in its [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/d689a0cb82f61d8b49dc858fa7a61744b8d56907/ndk-build):

```
This really is a tiny wrapper around GNU Make.
```

However it does handle a lot of small bits for you, so you should use it unless you have some strange setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have a make file, or don't plan to build your project for other platforms (iOS, Windows, Mac, Linux...), I would recommend going for `ndk-build`.

`Android.mk` is easier to construct and maintain, especially in regard to next upgrades of Android **NDK**. It's hard to forsee the future, but it has been straightforward to target new Android versions, new processors with NEON, v7, or x86 and MIPS.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. Or at laast not that I could find. 
ndk-build may be easier to use on small scale applications.
But when a real-world large build system is needed - just go with your own and be sure you use the toolchain from the android-ndk folder